# Number of read requests in GEE API

Tags: google-earth-engine, request

I got credential by using this command.

```
earthengine authenticate
```

I have linked with my account and saved authentication token successfully. I can get data from GEE and it's working well.

Where I can see Quota usage? There is also no info of using quota in this page. Please see attached file.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

To get to this screen, you have created a Google Project and enabled the EE API, right? If you would create a service account for that project, usage for that service account would show up on that screen.

Unfortunately, I don't think you can get to these stats for your regular user account. I'm happy to be proved wrong though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Apparently, I did create Google Project and enable EE API. Service account is created as well. But GEE didn't ask to link with service account or Google Project after running earthengine authenticate.

Comment: seems it's bug of GEE?

Comment: You don't use `earthengine authenticate` when you have a service account. https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/service_account

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I will try it out.

Comment: It's working well after GEE approved service account. Thanks a lot.